# poor accuracy of Capsule Network - mistake in the implementation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

I am working on a Capsule Network implementation that should be customizable. I found a code that is pretty straightforward (https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-capsule-network-in-tensorflow-11e4cca5ecae). I used the code and changed it to my needs.

However, I the code does not score the same accuracy on a test dataset (MNIST) as other implementations and the paper "Dynamic Routing between Capsules" suggest. Is there a possible mistake in the implementation of the capsule network? The code uses tf subclassing to create the CapsNet model.
Heres the class of the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class CapsuleNetwork(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, input_dimension, no_channels, no_of_convs, kernel_sizes, conv_strides, no_of_conv_kernels, no_of_primary_capsules, primary_capsule_vector, no_of_secondary_capsules, secondary_capsule_vector, r):
    super(CapsuleNetwork, self).__init__()
    self.input_dimension = input_dimension
    self.no_channels = no_channels
    self.no_of_convs = no_of_convs
    self.kernel_sizes = kernel_sizes
    self.conv_strides = conv_strides
    self.no_of_conv_kernels = no_of_conv_kernels
    self.no_of_primary_capsules = no_of_primary_capsules
    self.primary_capsule_vector = primary_capsule_vector
    self.no_of_secondary_capsules = no_of_secondary_capsules
    self.secondary_capsule_vector = secondary_capsule_vector
    self.r = r
    self.epsilon = 10e-7
    
    # calculating the number of primary capsules based on input image size and kernels/strides of the convolution (1152 in the paper)
    for i in range(self.no_of_convs):
        if i == 0:
            self.feature_map_dim = int(((input_dimension-self.kernel_sizes[i])/self.conv_strides[i])+1)
        else:
            self.feature_map_dim = int(((self.feature_map_dim-self.kernel_sizes[i])/self.conv_strides[i])+1)
            
    self.feature_map_dim = int(((self.feature_map_dim-self.kernel_sizes[-1])/self.conv_strides[-1])+1)
    self.no_primary_caps = int(self.feature_map_dim*self.feature_map_dim*self.no_of_primary_capsules)
    
    with tf.name_scope("Variables") as scope:
        self.conv_dict = {}
        for i in range(no_of_convs):
            self.conv_dict[f"convolution{i}"] = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(self.no_of_conv_kernels, [self.kernel_sizes[i],self.kernel_sizes[i]], strides=[self.conv_strides[i],self.conv_strides[i]], name=f'ConvolutionLayer_{i}', activation='relu')
        self.primary_capsule = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(self.no_of_primary_capsules * self.primary_capsule_vector, [self.kernel_sizes[-1],self.kernel_sizes[-1]], strides=[self.conv_strides[-1],self.conv_strides[-1]], name="PrimaryCapsule")
        self.w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal_initializer()(shape=[1, self.no_primary_caps, self.no_of_secondary_capsules, self.secondary_capsule_vector, self.primary_capsule_vector]), dtype=tf.float32, name="PoseEstimation", trainable=True)
        self.dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 512, activation='relu')
        self.dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1024, activation='relu')
        self.dense_3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = input_dimension*input_dimension*no_channels, activation='sigmoid', dtype='float32')
        
def print_architecture(self):
    print("Model Summary:\n")
    print("Input images: " + str(self.input_dimension) + "x" + str(self.input_dimension) + "x" + str(self.no_channels))
    print(str(self.no_of_convs) + " conv layers")
    print(str(self.no_of_primary_capsules) + " primary capsule channels with " + str(self.no_primary_caps) + " " + str(self.primary_capsule_vector) + "-D capsules")
    print(str(self.no_of_secondary_capsules) + " " + str(self.secondary_capsule_vector) + "-D digit capsules")
    
def build(self, input_shape):
    pass
    
def squash(self, s):
    with tf.name_scope("SquashFunction") as scope:
        s_norm = tf.norm(s, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        return tf.square(s_norm)/(1 + tf.square(s_norm)) * s/(s_norm + self.epsilon)

@tf.function
def call(self, inputs):
    input_x, y = inputs
    
    for i in range(self.no_of_convs):
        convolution = self.conv_dict.get(f"convolution{i}")
        if i == 0:
            x = convolution(input_x) # x.shape: (None, 20, 20, 256) JB:stimmt nun nicht mehr zwangsläufig
        else:
            x = convolution(x)
    x = self.primary_capsule(x) # x.shape: (None, 6, 6, 256)
    
    with tf.name_scope("CapsuleFormation") as scope:
        u = tf.reshape(x, (-1, self.no_of_primary_capsules * x.shape[1] * x.shape[2], self.primary_capsule_vector)) # u.shape: (None, 1152, 8)
        u = tf.expand_dims(u, axis=-2) # u.shape: (None, 1152, 1, 8)
        u = tf.expand_dims(u, axis=-1) # u.shape: (None, 1152, 1, 8, 1)
        u_hat = tf.matmul(self.w, u) # u_hat.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 16, 1)
        u_hat = tf.squeeze(u_hat, [4]) # u_hat.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 16)

    
    with tf.name_scope("DynamicRouting") as scope:
        b = tf.zeros((input_x.shape[0], self.no_primary_caps, self.no_of_secondary_capsules, 1)) # b.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 1)
        for i in range(self.r): # self.r = 3
            c = tf.nn.softmax(b, axis=-2) # c.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 1)
            s = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(c, u_hat), axis=1, keepdims=True) # s.shape: (None, 1, 10, 16)
            v = self.squash(s) # v.shape: (None, 1, 10, 16)
            agreement = tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(u_hat, axis=-1), tf.expand_dims(v, axis=-1), transpose_a=True), [4]) # agreement.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 1)
            # Before matmul following intermediate shapes are present, they are not assigned to a variable but just for understanding the code.
            # u_hat.shape (Intermediate shape) : (None, 1152, 10, 16, 1)
            # v.shape (Intermediate shape): (None, 1, 10, 16, 1)
            # Since the first parameter of matmul is to be transposed its shape becomes:(None, 1152, 10, 1, 16)
            # Now matmul is performed in the last two dimensions, and others are broadcasted
            # Before squeezing we have an intermediate shape of (None, 1152, 10, 1, 1)
            b += agreement
            
    with tf.name_scope("Masking") as scope:
        y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=-1) # y.shape: (None, 10, 1)
        y = tf.expand_dims(y, axis=1) # y.shape: (None, 1, 10, 1)
        mask = tf.cast(y, dtype=tf.float32) # mask.shape: (None, 1, 10, 1)
        v_masked = tf.multiply(mask, v) # v_masked.shape: (None, 1, 10, 16)
        
    with tf.name_scope("Reconstruction") as scope:
        v_ = tf.reshape(v_masked, [-1, self.no_of_secondary_capsules * self.secondary_capsule_vector]) # v_.shape: (None, 160)
        reconstructed_image = self.dense_1(v_) # reconstructed_image.shape: (None, 512)
        reconstructed_image = self.dense_2(reconstructed_image) # reconstructed_image.shape: (None, 1024)
        reconstructed_image = self.dense_3(reconstructed_image) # reconstructed_image.shape: (None, 784)
    return v, reconstructed_image

@tf.function
def predict_capsule_output(self, inputs):
    for i in range(self.no_of_convs):
        convolution = self.conv_dict.get(f"convolution{i}")
        if i == 0:
            x = convolution(inputs) # x.shape: (None, 20, 20, 256) JB:stimmt nun nicht mehr zwangsläufig
        else:
            x = convolution(x)
    x = self.primary_capsule(x) # x.shape: (None, 6, 6, 256)
    
    with tf.name_scope("CapsuleFormation") as scope:
        u = tf.reshape(x, (-1, self.no_of_primary_capsules * x.shape[1] * x.shape[2], self.primary_capsule_vector)) # u.shape: (None, 1152, 8)
        u = tf.expand_dims(u, axis=-2) # u.shape: (None, 1152, 1, 8)
        u = tf.expand_dims(u, axis=-1) # u.shape: (None, 1152, 1, 8, 1)
        u_hat = tf.matmul(self.w, u) # u_hat.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 16, 1)
        u_hat = tf.squeeze(u_hat, [4]) # u_hat.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 16)

    
    with tf.name_scope("DynamicRouting") as scope:
        b = tf.zeros((inputs.shape[0], self.no_primary_caps, self.no_of_secondary_capsules, 1)) # b.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 1)
        for i in range(self.r): # self.r = 3
            c = tf.nn.softmax(b, axis=-2) # c.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 1)
            s = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(c, u_hat), axis=1, keepdims=True) # s.shape: (None, 1, 10, 16)
            v = self.squash(s) # v.shape: (None, 1, 10, 16)
            agreement = tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(tf.expand_dims(u_hat, axis=-1), tf.expand_dims(v, axis=-1), transpose_a=True), [4]) # agreement.shape: (None, 1152, 10, 1)
            # Before matmul following intermediate shapes are present, they are not assigned to a variable but just for understanding the code.
            # u_hat.shape (Intermediate shape) : (None, 1152, 10, 16, 1)
            # v.shape (Intermediate shape): (None, 1, 10, 16, 1)
            # Since the first parameter of matmul is to be transposed its shape becomes:(None, 1152, 10, 1, 16)
            # Now matmul is performed in the last two dimensions, and others are broadcasted
            # Before squeezing we have an intermediate shape of (None, 1152, 10, 1, 1)
            b += agreement
    return v

@tf.function
def regenerate_image(self, inputs):
    v, pred_class = inputs
    with tf.name_scope("Reconstruction") as scope:
        v_ = tf.reshape(v, [-1, self.no_of_secondary_capsules * self.secondary_capsule_vector]) # v_.shape: (None, 160)
        reconstructed_image = self.dense_1(v_) # reconstructed_image.shape: (None, 512)
        reconstructed_image = self.dense_2(reconstructed_image) # reconstructed_image.shape: (None, 1024)
        reconstructed_image = self.dense_3(reconstructed_image) # reconstructed_image.shape: (None, 3072)
        
    return reconstructed_image
```

There is an additional script that makes use of this class and trains a model. The main parts are:

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from CapsuleNetworkClassWorkingExample import CapsuleNetwork

print(tf.__version__)

# =============================================================================
# Hyperparameter based on paper
epsilon = 1e-7
m_plus = 0.9
m_minus = 0.1
lambda_ = 0.5
alpha = 0.0005
epochs = 50
no_of_secondary_capsules = 10
batch_size = 64

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

# parameters for CapsNet architecture
params = {
"input_dimension": 28,
"no_channels": 1,                 # 3 for rgb or 1 for gray-scale images
"no_of_convs": 1,
"kernel_sizes": (9,9),            # kernel sizes of convolutional layers. First entry: kernel of conv0; second entry: kernel of conv1 etc...
"conv_strides": (1,2),            # strides of the convolutional layers. see "kernel_sizes"
"no_of_conv_kernels": 256,        # number of kernels for all conv layers (including primary capsule convolution layer)
"no_of_primary_capsules": 32,     # number of primary capsule channels
"no_of_secondary_capsules": 10,   # number of digit capsules (has to be equal to number of classes)
"primary_capsule_vector": 8,      # dimension of primary capsules
"secondary_capsule_vector": 16,   # dimension of digit capsules 
"r":3,                            # number of routing iterations
}
# =============================================================================
# Save directory for np arrays (losses & acc)
loss_acc_path = './logs/losses_acc'
# Tensorboard Checkpoints
checkpoint_path = './logs/model/capsule'

stamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

logdir = './logs/func/%s' % stamp
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)

scalar_logdir = './logs/scalars/%s' % stamp
file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(scalar_logdir + "/metrics")

# Import MNIST and divide into train, val and test dataset [left out here]

# functions to evaluate loss, and train the model
def safe_norm(v, axis=-1, epsilon=1e-7):
    """"
    input:
        v → digit capsule output of dimension (None, 1, 10, 16) dimension varies for number of labels
        axis → integer value
        epsilon → needed to not receive NaN
    output:
        normalization of input v
    """
    v_ = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(v), axis = axis, keepdims=True)
    return tf.sqrt(v_ + epsilon)

def loss_function(v, reconstructed_image, y, y_image):
    prediction = safe_norm(v)
    prediction = tf.reshape(prediction, [-1, no_of_secondary_capsules])    

    left_margin = tf.square(tf.maximum(0.0, m_plus - prediction))
    right_margin = tf.square(tf.maximum(0.0, prediction - m_minus))
    
    l = tf.add(y * left_margin, lambda_ * (1.0 - y) * right_margin)

    margin_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(l, axis=-1))

    y_image_flat = tf.reshape(y_image, [-1, 
params.get("input_dimension")*params.get("input_dimension")*params.get("no_channels")]) 
#reshape depends on input shape
    reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_image_flat - reconstructed_image))

    loss = tf.add(margin_loss, alpha * reconstruction_loss)

    return loss

def train(x,y):
        y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(y, depth=10)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        v, reconstructed_image = model([x, y_one_hot])
        loss = loss_function(v, reconstructed_image, y_one_hot, x)
    grad = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad, model.trainable_variables))
    return loss

def predict(model, x):
    pred = safe_norm(model.predict_capsule_output(x))
    pred = tf.squeeze(pred, [1])
    return np.argmax(pred, axis=1)[:,0]
tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)

# create the model
model = CapsuleNetwork(**params)

model.print_architecture()

_ = train(X_train[:32],y_train[:32])

tf.summary.trace_off()
model.summary()

checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(model=model)

train_losses = []
val_losses = []
val_accuracy = []
for i in range(1, epochs+1, 1):

    loss = 0
    with tqdm(total=len(train_dataset)) as pbar:
    
        description = "Epoch " + str(i) + "/" + str(epochs)
        pbar.set_description_str(description)

        for X_batch, y_batch in train_dataset:

            loss += train(X_batch,y_batch)
            pbar.update(1)

        loss /= len(train_dataset)
        train_losses.append(loss.numpy())
    
        training_sum = 0

        print_statement = "Training Loss :" + str(loss.numpy()) + " Evaluating Validation Loss and Accuracy ..."
        pbar.set_postfix_str(print_statement)
    
        epoch_val_loss = []
        for X_batch, y_batch in val_dataset:
            training_sum += sum(predict(model, X_batch)==y_batch.numpy())
            y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(y_batch, depth=10)
            v = model.predict_capsule_output(X_batch)
            pred_class = predict(model,X_batch)
            reconstruction = model.regenerate_image((v,pred_class))
            val_loss = loss_function(v,reconstruction,y_one_hot,X_batch)
            epoch_val_loss.append(val_loss)
        val_accuracy.append(training_sum/val_dataset_size)
        val_losses.append(np.mean(epoch_val_loss))
    
        with file_writer.as_default():
            tf.summary.scalar('Training Loss', data=loss.numpy(), step=i)
            tf.summary.scalar(' Validation Accuracy', data=val_accuracy[-1], step=i)
            tf.summary.scalar(' Validation Loss', data=val_losses[-1], step=i)
    
        print_statement = "Train Loss :" + str(loss.numpy()) + "Val Accuracy :" + str(val_accuracy[-1]) + "Val Loss :" + str(val_losses[-1])
    
        if i != 1:
            if train_losses[i-1] < np.amin(train_losses[:-1]):
                print_statement += ' Checkpoint Saved'
                checkpoint.save(checkpoint_path)
        else:
            print_statement += ' Checkpoint Saved'
            checkpoint.save(checkpoint_path)
        
    
        pbar.set_postfix_str(print_statement)
```

Now, when I evaluate the test accuracy by predicting the class outputs of the test datasets I obtain a accuracy of ~98% (depending on the checkpoint). This is roughly 1% less than other implementations achieve. I don't really understand why this is the case. Below, you can see the learning curves of the model. I hope someone can give a hint why my results might differ from other peoples codes.
[Learning Curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPkQQ.png)

Comment: A difference of 1% is not "poor accuracy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not having looked at your code in detail 1% difference is really not a lot when working with deep learning. The difference might be cause by a different (random) weight initialisation or slightly different gradients that lead to a different learning trajectory. Re-training the network might thus lead to slightly different results each time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Retraining the model always results in a test error of 1.5 to 2 percent, while ideally I want something around 0.3 to 0.5 percent. Maybe I just have to accept that.
Apart from that, the validation loss and accuracy doesn't seem to improve whereas the training loss does. This applies to the MNIST dataset. When trained on CIFAR10 both losses (Val and train) improve with each epoch. What can be the reason for that? Is the model possibly over fitting on MNIST?

Comment: Yes, you might indeed see overfitting. You could try to regularise your network (using dropout, a smaller network, [etc](https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/regularization.html)) to improve the performance on the MNIST dataset.